# Re-run the execution if api call fails - [ Python2.7]

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, networking

I am running a code which fetches json data from an API url, scenario is I am trying for an custom exception while the URL response is not fetched (sometimes the response shows 200 still it doesn't fetches the data) in this case the code should re-execute from the beginning.

code:

```
import json
import urllib
url = 'www.google.com'
status = url.getcode()
if(status != 200):
   # re-execute the code
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
if (data == null):
   #re-execute the code
```

Couldn't find a suitable solution for the same while searching through internet

can anybody help on this ?

Comment: What about using a loop? In addition `null` does not exist in Python, you can use `data is None` or `if not data` to validate that.

Comment: what is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could help you, following the logic you have so far:

```
import json
import urllib

url = 'www.google.com'

while True:
    status = url.getcode()
    if status != 200:
        continue
    data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    if not data:
        continue
    break
```

You can also improve it a little bit by:

```
import json
import urllib

url = 'www.google.com'
status = url.getcode()
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))

while status != 200 or not data:
    status = url.getcode()
    data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import urllib

URL = 'www.google.com'

def get_data_status(url):
    return (json.load(urllib.urlopen(url)), url.getcode())

while 1:
    data, status = get_data_status(URL)
    if data  and (status==200): 
        break
```

None, False, empty strings, empty dictionaries, empty arrays, and 0 are false values.  I don't think you were using null correctly. When Python decodes JSON, it turns null into it's null object, which is None.

ETA: regarding comments:

> If the api is not having any data it returns the response as null hence given null
>
> i have few more lines to execute after 'if(data == null)'

ok so if you're really getting str(null) back from the json request and you want to "execute a few more lines of code" upon that event:

```
while 1:
    data, status = get_data_status(URL)
    if (data!='null')  and (status==200): 
        break
    elif (data='null'):
        print 'execute a few more lines of "null" data code'
    elif (status!=200):
        print 'execute a few more lines of wrong status code'

print 'exiting while loop with good data and status 200'
```

Comment: this generates two errors errors: 1. `status` and `data` are not defined. 2. `null` does not exist in Python

Comment: yes I caught the first two, was editing as you commented.  not sure what the op means by the null response?

Comment: I agree with you. Probably `null` is a variable, but since I saw the imports which usually are at the beginning of the file, I assumed the one who asked has experience with Java.

Comment: Thanks for the response
If the api is not having any data it returns the response as null hence given null , I am aware of the use of None in python :-)

Comment: will this reexecute the code from top i have few more lines to execute after 'if(data == null)'